# How to mount current directory as read-only but still allow changes inside the container?

Tags: docker, docker-for-mac

I have a situation where:

- I want to mount a directory ~/tmp/mycode to /mycode readonly
- I want to be able to edit the files in the directory, so I can't just run `-v /my/local/path/tmp/mycode:/mycode`

  - I want it to not persist changes on the host filesystem though so I can't mount it read/write
- ~/tmp/mycode is rather large

Basically I want to be able to edit the files in the mounted volume but not have those changes persisted.

My current workflow is to create a dummy container using a dockerfile:

```
ADD . /mycode
```

and then execute that container.

However as the repository grows, this step takes longer and longer to perform, because the only way I can think is to make a complete copy of ~/tmp/mycode in order to be able to manipulate the files in the container.

I've also thought about mounting the directory and copying it inside the container and committing that container, but that has the same issue.

Is there a way to run a docker container to allow file edits without persisting them on the host short of copying the whole directory?

I am using the latest docker for mac, currently Version 17.03.1-ce-mac5 (16048).

Comment: as the directory seems to be a (git?) repository, wouldn't it be easier to actually mount it read-write, stash your current branch state, allow host filesystem changes and then perform a hard reset and unstash your previous state back to where it was when the container is stopped?

Comment: @ZathrusWriter that _could_ work, though an errant `rm -rf .git` would make that strategy pretty traumatic...

Answer (score 1):

This is fairly trivial to do with docker and overlay:

```
docker run --name myenv --privileged -v /my/local/path/tmp/mycode:/mnt/rocode:ro -it ubuntu /bin/bash
docker exec -d myenv /sbin/mount -t overlay overlay -o lowerdir=/mnt/rocode,upperdir=/mycode,workdir=/mnt/code-workdir /mycode
```

This should mount the code from your directory read only and create the overlay inside the container so that /mnt/rocode is read only, but /mycode is writable.

Make sure that your kernel is 3.18+ and that you have overlay in your /proc/filesystems.