# Docker - mount a volume rw from container perspective, ro from host perspective

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, volume

**Current scenario:**

I have ~50 AWS instances with ~350 GB on each instance. When a build request comes, an instance is taken, a docker container is launched with those ~350 GB as a volume inside container.
With this, even if I have one build, I have to pay for 50 instances and 50 EBS storages. When I have 100 build requests, 50 have to wait, because I cannot scale so easy.

**Desired scenario:**

I would like to scale in and out with the number of builds I have. Because I cannot copy almost instantly that 350 GB data from a share drive (eg: EFS) I was thinking if it is possible to mount the **volume in read write mode from container perspective and read only mode from host perspective.**
With this, I can mount the same EFS to 50 instances to serve 50 builds.
The additional data that is written by the build system can be lost when the container is terminated, the useful data is saved to artifacts.

Do you have any suggestions for me?

Comment: [How to mount current directory as read-only but still allow changes inside the container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43265388/how-to-mount-current-directory-as-read-only-but-still-allow-changes-inside-the-c) seems to have an answer for this, manually invoking the overlay filesystem.

Comment: Also here I've found additional details using the same method (overlay filesystem):
https://serverfault.com/questions/841238/how-to-use-overlayfs-with-docker-volumes
Thank you for your hint! I'll analyze this solution. It sounds interesting.